# How to download data onto multiple sheets from shiny?

Tags: r, excel, shiny

**How can we download data from Shiny onto multiple sheets naming each sheet ?**

For example, below, ginberg saved the mtcars data in sheet1, 
can we save the head(mtcars) in sheet2 ?
Also, can we name these sheet differently e.g sheet_data, sheet_head

Reference:https://community.rstudio.com/t/r-shiny-to-download-xlsx-file/18441/3
Code from https://community.rstudio.com/u/ginberg

```
library(writexl)
ui <- fluidPage(
  downloadButton("dl", "Download")
)
server <- function(input, output) {
  data <- mtcars

  output$dl <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() { "ae.xlsx"},
    content = function(file) {write_xlsx(data, path = file)}
  )

      ### Trial 1
      # output$dl <- downloadHandler(
      #   filename = function() { "ae.xlsx"},
      #   content = function(file) {        
      #     fname <- paste(file,"xlsx",sep=".")
      #     wb <- loadWorkbook(fname, create = T)#createWorkbook()
      #     createSheet(wb, name = "data")
      #     writeWorksheet(wb, head(mtcars), sheet = "sheet_head")
      #     saveWorkbook(wb)
      #     file.rename(fname, file)}

      # Trial 2
      # filename = function() {"both_data.xlsx"},
      # content = function(file) {
      #   write_xlsx(mtcars, file="sheet_data.xlsx")
      #   write_xlsx(head(mtcars), file="sheet_head.xlsx")
      #   
      #   channel <- odbcConnectExcel(xls.file = file,readOnly=FALSE)
      #   sqlSave(channel, mtcars, tablename = "sheet_data")
      #   sqlSave(channel,  head(mtcars), tablename = "sheet_head")
      #   odbcClose(channel)

  )
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can name sheets and include different data frames on different sheets.

Using `write_xlsx`, you can provide a named `list` of data frames.

For example:

```
server <- function(input, output) {

  data_list <- reactive({
    list(
      sheet_data = mtcars,
      sheet_head = head(mtcars)
    )
  })

  output$dl <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {"ae.xlsx"},
    content = function(file) {write_xlsx(data_list(), path = file)}
  )
}
```

The `list` was created in a `reactive` function expecting you may wish to change the included data depending on user interactions.

Comment: Thanks Ben for precise solution. In write_xlsx, path = file is necessary to make this work but can you briefly share your thoughts on this. I looked into documentation, it is mentioned, path = tempfile(fileext = ".xlsx")

Comment: `write_xlsx` wants a path containing the file to write to - the default for `path` is `tempfile(fileext = "xlsx")` - if you *don't* include `path = file` in your `write_xlsx` it would use a temporary directory and filename and write your excel file there. in your environment, to find where your temporary directory is, type `tempdir()` in your console. in your example code above, `file` will contain the path and filename after the `downloadHandler` dialog box has been dismissed, as it is passed into your `content` function as the `file` argument.