# How to have a single download button for all datatables in R shiny webpage

Tags: r, shiny, datatable, download

I am working with a shiny app where it is desired to have a single `downloadButton` in the header of the application that downloads the data table present in the current/active page/tab.

Below is a simple app that has two data tables in page1 and one in page 2. Each data table has the `csv` , `excel` buttons on top of each data table.

Could these `csv`,  `excel` buttons be removed and place a single `downloadButton` in a fixed position in the `header` bar that offers to download csv/excel options of the active table in the current page or tab.

The idea is to have a  single fixed `downloadButton` for the entire app in the header bar. Any possible solutions within shiny to do this or if anyone has attempted this before.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Header",
                  dropdownMenuOutput("updatedTimeOutput"),
                  dropdownMenu(type = "notifications", 
                               badgeStatus = "warning",
                               icon = icon("bullhorn", "fa-lg"),
                               notificationItem(icon = icon("bullhorn", "fa-1x"),
                                                status = "info",
                                                text = tags$span(
                                                  tags$b("Please notice!")
                                                )
                               ))),
  dashboardSidebar( sidebarMenu(id = "tabs",
                                menuItem("Page1", tabName = "page1"),
                                menuItem("Page2", tabName = "page2"))),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(
        tabName = "page1",

      tabBox(id="tabs",
      tabPanel("tab1",
          column(12,
                 DT::dataTableOutput("table1")
                 )),
       
       tabPanel( "tab2",
          column(12,
                DT::dataTableOutput("table2")
                ))
       )
      )
      ,
      tabItem(
        tabName = "page2",
        fluidRow(
          column(12,
                 DT::dataTableOutput("table3")
          ))
      )
    )
    )
    )



server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$table1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    datatable( data = mtcars,
               options = DToptions,
               extensions = 'Buttons',
               rownames = TRUE,
               selection = 'none'
    )
  })
  
  output$table2 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    datatable( data = mtcars,
               options = DToptions,
               extensions = 'Buttons',
               rownames = TRUE,
               selection = 'none'
    )
  })
    
  output$table3 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    datatable( data = mtcars,
               options = DToptions,
               extensions = 'Buttons',
               rownames = TRUE,
               selection = 'none'
    )
  })
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a) If you only want "one downloadButton visible in the header common to all pages that downloads the table in the active page or tab", it needs firstly to know the active page and tab based on the page / tab IDs. (b) If you only need a single button to download all the tables, you can download them into a .xlsx file (see [download data onto multiple sheets from shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59071409/how-to-download-data-onto-multiple-sheets-from-shiny)). (c)If you need a button for each tab, place the button in each tab and you can simply save table as .csv.
Here is the code for situation (a).

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Header",
                  dropdownMenuOutput("updatedTimeOutput"),
                  dropdownMenu(type = "notifications", 
                               badgeStatus = "warning",
                               icon = icon("bullhorn", "fa-lg"),
                               notificationItem(icon = icon("bullhorn", "fa-1x"),
                                                status = "info",
                                                text = tags$span(
                                                  tags$b("Please notice!")
                                                )
                               ))),
  dashboardSidebar( sidebarMenu(id = "pages", # use unique id for pages
                                menuItem("Page1", tabName = "page1"),
                                menuItem("Page2", tabName = "page2"))),
  dashboardBody(
    
    # Add download button 
    downloadButton('downloadData', 'Download Table',
                   style="font-weight:bold;"
    ),
    helpText(
      hr(style = "border-top: 1px solid #000000;"), 
    ),
    
    tabItems(
      tabItem(
        tabName = "page1",

         tabsetPanel(id="tabs",
                      
               tabPanel("tab1",

                        column(12,
                               DT::dataTableOutput("table1")
                        )),
               
               tabPanel( "tab2",

                         column(12,
                                DT::dataTableOutput("table2")
                         ))
        )
      )
      ,
      tabItem(
        tabName = "page2",
        fluidRow(
          column(12,
                 DT::dataTableOutput("table3")
          ))
      )
    )
  )
)



server <- function(input, output) {
  
  # table1
  tbl1 <- mtcars[1:30, ] # tables 1, 2, 3 use different rows of mtcars to differentiate tables
  
  output$table1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    datatable( tbl1,
               #    options = DToptions, # no such object called "DToptions"
               extensions = 'Buttons',
               rownames = TRUE,
               selection = 'none'
    )
  })
  
  
  # table2
  tbl2 <-  mtcars[5:45, ]
  
  output$table2 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    datatable( tbl2,
               #    options = DToptions,
               extensions = 'Buttons',
               rownames = TRUE,
               selection = 'none'
    )
  })
  
  # table3
  tbl3 <-  mtcars[11:35, ]
  
  output$table3 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    datatable( tbl3,
               #    options = DToptions,
               extensions = 'Buttons',
               rownames = TRUE,
               selection = 'none'
    )
  })
  

  page_name <- reactive({
    input$pages
  })
  
  # select table on the active page / tab
  selected_table <- reactive({
    if(page_name() == "page1"){
      tbl.list <- list("tab1" = tbl1, "tab2" = tbl2)
      select_tbl <- tbl.list[input$tabs]
    }else{
      select_tbl <- tbl3
    }
    return(select_tbl)
  })
  
  # download table
  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {"table.csv"},
    content = function(file) {write.csv(selected_table(), file, row.names=TRUE)}   
  )    
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: the idea is not to download all tables at once. The intention is to download the table in the current page or tab using a `downloadbutton` that is visible in the `header bar`. If the user is in page1 and tab1, then the `downloadbutton` should trigger download of the table in page1 and tab1. If the user is in page2, the `downloadbutton` should get table3 in page 2, likewise

Comment: I have modified the code. Now you can use `downloadbutton` in each tab or page.

Comment: In the OP it is mentioned "single fixed `downloadButton` for the entire app in the header bar". There should be only one `downloadButton` visible in the `header` common to all pages that downloads the table in the active page or tab but not having 3 buttons for 3 tables.

Comment: I see. Then it needs to know what page and tab a user has selected. See the modified code.

Comment: it works, is it possible to offer download csv or excel upon the clicking downloadbutton?

Comment: You can add a radio button beside the download button.  See code below.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)
library(writexl)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Header",
                  dropdownMenuOutput("updatedTimeOutput"),
                  dropdownMenu(type = "notifications", 
                               badgeStatus = "warning",
                               icon = icon("bullhorn", "fa-lg"),
                               notificationItem(icon = icon("bullhorn", "fa-1x"),
                                                status = "info",
                                                text = tags$span(
                                                  tags$b("Please notice!")
                                                )
                               ))),
  
  dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(id = "pages", # use unique id for pages
                                menuItem("Page1", tabName = "page1"),
                                menuItem("Page2", tabName = "page2"))),
  
  dashboardBody(
    
    # Add download button and radioButton
    fluidRow(
      column(3,
             downloadButton('downloadData', 'Download Table',
                            style="font-weight:bold;"
             ),
             helpText(
               hr(style = "border-top: 1px solid #000000;"), 
             )),
      column(3, 
             radioButtons("f", "Download format:",
                          c("csv" = "csv",
                            "Excel" = "xlsx"), inline=T) 
    )),
    
    tabItems(
      tabItem(
        tabName = "page1",

         tabsetPanel(id="tabs",
                      
               tabPanel("tab1",

                        column(12,
                               DT::dataTableOutput("table1")
                        )),
               
               tabPanel( "tab2",

                         column(12,
                                DT::dataTableOutput("table2")
                         ))
        )
      )),
     
      tabItem(
        tabName = "page2",
        fluidRow(
          column(12,
                 DT::dataTableOutput("table3")
          ))
      )
    )
)



server <- function(input, output) {
  
  # table1
  tbl1 <- mtcars[1:30, ] # tables 1, 2, 3 use different rows of mtcars to differentiate tables
  
  output$table1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    datatable( tbl1,
               #    options = DToptions, # no such object called "DToptions"
               extensions = 'Buttons',
               rownames = TRUE,
               selection = 'none'
    )
  })
  
  
  # table2
  tbl2 <-  mtcars[5:45, ]
  
  output$table2 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    datatable( tbl2,
               #    options = DToptions,
               extensions = 'Buttons',
               rownames = TRUE,
               selection = 'none'
    )
  })
  
  # table3
  tbl3 <-  mtcars[11:35, ]
  
  output$table3 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    datatable( tbl3,
               #    options = DToptions,
               extensions = 'Buttons',
               rownames = TRUE,
               selection = 'none'
    )
  })
  

  page_name <- reactive({
    input$pages
  })
  
  # select table on the active page / tab
  selected_table <- reactive({
    if(page_name() == "page1"){
      tbl.list <- list("tab1" = tbl1, "tab2" = tbl2)
      select_tbl <- tbl.list[input$tabs]
    }else{
      select_tbl <- tbl3
    }
    return(select_tbl)
  })
  
  # select download format
  select_format <- reactive(input$f)
  
  # download table
    output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
      filename = function(){
        if(select_format() == "csv"){
          {"table.csv"}
      }else{
        {"table.xlsx"}
       }
      } ,
      content = function(file){
        if(select_format() == "csv"){
          {write.csv(selected_table(), file, row.names=TRUE)}
        }else{
          {write_xlsx(selected_table(), file)}
        }  
      } 
    )

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```